How can I trace who activated a certain API on GCP?
I'm looking at our GCP bill and there's this API that someone activated, which generated a huge consumption, but no one on our team activated it. We're suspecting that we could have been vulnerated.
I do see on the billing dashboard when was the API activated. Is there a way to trace who (which IP) did it?

Yes, you should be able to get it from the admin activity logs if the API was activated within the time range of the retention period for the logs.
Here is a sample query you can use in cloud logging - replace project id and API service name.
log_name="projects/[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
protoPayload.request.name="projects/YOUR-PROJECT-ID/services/[APINAMEHERE].googleapis.com"
protoPayload.authorizationInfo.permission="serviceusage.services.enable"


In the output look for principalEmail as to who enabled the API.

We don't have them activated. Additionally, we know (if vulnerated) which user the activation was given to. What we want to know is if this action was done from another IP.

yes, the activity logs show the callerIp in the requestMetadata field, which is the source IP of the requester.
